# Seeing how many values in two SparkR columns match

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I have two integer columns (`x1` and `x2`) in a `SparkR` `DataFrame` named `df` that are very similar to each other. I want to get a count of how many of the values match and compare it with the total length of the columns. How can I do this? I have tried the following, both of which result in errors.

```
agg(df, sum(df$x1==df$x2))
collect(sum(df$x1==df$x2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically, here's the code to the answer:

```
df <- withColumn(df, 'x', df$x1==df$x2)
head(agg(groupBy(df, 'x'), x="count"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/R/withColumn.html) to generate the new column populating a value for both `x1` and `x2` columns being equal.

And you can use [count](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/R/count.html) to `count` the values from new column.